# How to cascade two routers

Tags: routing, router

When I connect two (Zyxel) routers in a cascade configuration, I don't know how to set the right address on the Lan Interface between the outer router (the one on the top of the diagram) and the inner. In the picture below I drew two example diagrams. The first is a simple router to router connection, while in the second example, I have set the outer router  in the bridge mode.
What is the right Lan interface address for the outer router in the both cases?

[image: Example]

Comment: Sadly your Zyxel routers are off-topic here; please consider asking on [su]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R2 LAN IP should be in Same network as WAN Interface. In other hand, R2 LAN IP should be in same subnet as R1 WAN Interface.

In your second diagram there is no requirement for IP address because it is in bridge mode. When Router in Bridge mode it does not support to IP Routing. It may have requirement of Layer 2 configurations.

> A network bridge is a layer 2 device (typically a switch), using MAC
>   addresses with ethernet. A router is a layer 3 device (typically a
>   router), using IP address with ethernet. So a router, in bridge mode,
>   doesn’t route, it switches, meaning there’s no IP routing or NAT
>   between networks, it simply extends the layer 2 domain across the
>   device so that the “WAN” port of the router, and the “LAN” ports of
>   the switch, are all in the same LAN with no routing (or layer 3)
>   network separation.

[Reference](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-bridge-mode-in-a-router)

Comment: You have said: "R2 LAN IP  in Same network as WAN Interface". My doubt is: "should be" or "have to be" ? In my tests it works whatever the address I use. while logically I think "R2 LAN IP" and "R1 WAN IP" must be on the same subnet.

Comment: The theory and practice sometimes seem not to coincide. Infact, in the second example, when I configure the router in bridge mode, it asks me for the address for the VLAN on the LAN interface.

Comment: Yes. It is must. R2 LAN IP must be in same subnet which used in R1 WAN.

Comment: VLAN is a Layer 2 configuration, You need to create separate VLAN to start Communications. What is a device modal?

Comment: The router is a Zyxel SBG5500-A. In bridge mode, it requires a VLAN setup, with a relative ip address for the Lan interface.

Comment: @AndreaBorgogelliAvveduti, i am not familiar with that device modal. by googling you can find how to configure vlan on router.

Answer (score 1):

In between routers, you can choose any IP subnet you like, preferrably a private IP subnet that doesn't interfere with anything else in the network.

If the bottom router's upward interface uses 10.10.10.1/24(?) you need to use any other address from 10.10.10.0/24 on the upper router's downward interface - both interfaces need to use the same subnet.